# New 4k Monitor hooked to laptop frequently goes black for a second then back to normal

Tags: laptop, display, external-display, windows-10-v1709

I have an ASUS Strix 15" laptop with a 980m video card.  I just bought an AOC U2879G6 monitor.  It runs great 90% of the time but some days it will intermittently "go black" then come back to life while I'm actively using it.  Cables are tight.  Drivers are up to date.  What else might cause this?  It seems to only happen when running at 4k (even on desktop).

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that there's enough interference in the video signal that the receiver is intermittently losing sync.

Things to try:

1. Use as short of a video cable as possible. Longer cables are more prone to interference.
2. Use a higher quality video cable. If your monitor is connected with DisplayPort, make sure the cable is rated for DisplayPort 1.2 or later.
3. If you are using a high refresh rate on the monitor, switch to a lower rate.